# How to import data for Graph database in Azure Cosmos DB?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

The documentations indicate that there is a Data Migration Tool that only works when importing data into Azure Cosmos DB for use with the DocumentDB API but not table API or Graph API. So, is there any way to import data from other sources to use in CosmosDB graph database?

Comment: Console app in this sample may help you to upload the sample data for Graph database in Azure Cosmos DB.
(As mentioned under section **Uploading the sample data**). https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-cosmos-db-dotnet-graphexplorer

Answer (score 0):

I scratched my itch of this variety by downloading the Graph API demo project

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-cosmos-db-graph-dotnet-getting-started

and then using a text file, built up the queries by hand:

```
--INIT
--g.V().drop()


--CREATE
------
--vertex
g.addV('person').property('id', 'dave').property('firstName', 'Dave').property('lastName', 'Andersen').property('age', 49)
g.addV('person').property('id', 'mary').property('firstName', 'Mary').property('lastName', 'Andersen').property('age', 39)
--edge
g.V('dave').addE('knows').to(g.V('mary'))


--READ
--filter
--g.V().hasLabel('person').order().by('firstName', decr)
--project
--g.V().hasLabel('person').values('firstName')
--traverse
--g.V('thomas').outE('knows').inV().hasLabel('person')
--loop
--g.V('thomas').repeat(out()).until(has('id', 'robin')).path()
--g.V().count()
--g.E().count()


--UPDATE
--------
--g.V('thomas').property('age', 44)


--DELETE
--dropedge
--g.V('thomas').outE('knows').where(inV().has('id', 'mary')).drop()
--dropvertex
--g.V('thomas').drop()
```

and then cycle through it from code:

```
string queriesPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "queries.txt";

            var queries = File.ReadAllLines(queriesPath).Where(l => !l.StartsWith("--") && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(l));

            foreach (var query in queries)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Running " + query);

                IDocumentQuery<dynamic> gremlinQuery = client.CreateGremlinQuery<dynamic>(graph, query);
                while (gremlinQuery.HasMoreResults)
                {
                    foreach (dynamic result in await gremlinQuery.ExecuteNextAsync())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"\t {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result)}");
                    }
                }

                Console.WriteLine();
            }
```

Comment: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-cosmos-db-graph-dotnet-getting-started is not working. Could you please provide the correct URL? Is there any way to import data from sql database to cosmos graph db?

Comment: appears to have moved to: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-cosmos-db-graph-gremlindotnet-getting-started

Answer (score 0):

For graph api, it depends what database you are using.

- for neo4j there is this repo: https://github.com/bsherwin/neo2cosmos
- for arangodb, I was able to use the  Data Migration Tool which uploads the set of vertices and edges as json, then you could write a simple stored procedure to connect connect the verticies.

I am stuck at the point of querying across graph collections (which seems not supported) so we might upload the edges and vertices in the same collection and use the script to make the edges